# By use moment javascript I need to add hours only (without increase or add minutes) / round to nearest hour or month or year

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

By use moment js, When I want to add One hour to current time, I only want to increase the hour and Not the minutes? So the time 03:25 will be 04:00 and not 04:25 (which is wrong)

```
// below increase 60 minutes while I only need to round to the nearest hour
$('#eventTime').val(moment().add(1, 'hours').format('HH:mm'));
```

Hope the solution will work also when round to nearest month (get to first day of next month) or year and so on ...

Comment: Are you trying to round the time up to the next hour?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `startOf` method:

```
moment().startOf('hour').add(1, 'hours').format('HH:mm')
```